# How to convert binary number to array?

Tags: regex, matlab, math, binary, type-conversion

**Input**

`1001001110`

**Intended output**

```
[1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0]
```

*P.s. some regex like `regexp('1001001110',[10])` may be able to do this but requires non-replacing token.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
array = ismember(binarynumber,'1')
```

e.g.

```
A = ismember('1010','1')
```

returns

```
1 0 1 0
```

logic though, but you can transform it using `double(A)`. Improvement over your method is, that you directly get numbers instead of chars, assuming you want this.

and backwards:

```
binary = sprintf('%d',A)
```

returns:

```
B = 
     1010
```

Comment: How do you do this in the opposite direction? Binary number in array to binary?

Answer (score 0):

**Regex** but the ismember better in the other answer.

```
>> a=regexp('1001001110','[^a]','match')

a = 

  Columns 1 through 9

    '1'    '0'    '0'    '1'    '0'    '0'    '1'    '1'    '1'

  Column 10

    '0'
```

**Do not use Dec2bin and then the above, instead use de2bi directly**

```
>> de2bi(12)

ans =

     0     0     1     1
```